# why does my code on insert into table comes with error warning

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have been trying to do away with sql mode and i have come across this here SET SQL_MODE = ''; after trying out this code got this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, lname, pwd, email, phone, gender, is_active, utype' at line 1"

can someone help me figure out whats wrong

This is my code:

```
$sql = " SET SQL_MODE = '';INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, lname, pwd, email, phone, gender, is_active, utype, pics, bdate)
            VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', PASSWORD('$pwd'), '$email', '$phone', '$gender', 'FALSE', 'USER', '$thumbnail', NOW())";
```

can someone help me figure out whats wrong , i am trying to do away with the SQL mode so as to fix column doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute multiple SQL statements at once, which is for security reasons (in most drivers) not supported by default.

You can either execute your commands step by step or depending on the programming language/driver you can set an option which allows execution of multiple statements.

PHP's mysqli extension for example doesn't offer this option, but has a separate function `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Please note that you need to process all result set and error packages from the executed commands before you can send new commands to the server.